# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrpm collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: centos

I installed the rpm package as well but have this issue while building my code. 
I also see that the rmp -q command tells me I have rpm-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 installed as well.
Not sure if I am missing any configuration somewhere

Comment: You are likely missing the `rpm-devel` package.

Comment: You might want to install `rpm-devel` and `rpm-libs`, too.

Comment: What was the command you executed to see the resulting message?

Comment: @Kolban The make file was running     gcc-4.4.7 -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_serialization -lboost_wserialization -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lrpm -lrpmio -Wl,etc etc

Comment: Etan and Markus I tried installing devvel an libs